# How do I easily put the contents of my array into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently trying to add rows to a dataframe. I have 3 variables, stft, cqt and feature_extract, but I have 22 columns and 20 of my features are in feature_extract. I want to do something like this

```
df_feats = df_feats.append(pd.Series([stft, cqt, feature_extract], index=df_feats.columns), ignore_index=True)
```

But I obviously get an error since it says there are too many columns. The alternative would be to do something like this

```
df_feats = df_feats.append(pd.Series([stft, cqt, feature_extract[0], ...feature_extract[19]], index=df_feats.columns), ignore_index=True)
```

But writing it all out doesn't seem to make sense. Especially if I plan to change things around later. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

So we have two single items `stft` and `cqt`, and a list `feature_extract` of 20 more items, and we want to produce a list with the 22 items?

That is spelled `[stft, cqt] + feature_extract`.

Comment: stft, and cqt are not really single items. They are both matrices that take up a column